# Golang send get 400 but curl is correct

Tags: go, http, curl

I use golang send http get to a url it return 400 ,but i using the curl ie will give me the correct 200.below is my code

```
func TestParseUrl(t *testing.T) {
    originUrl := "https://auth0.openai.com/authorize?client_id=TdJIcbe16WoTHtN95nyywh5E4yOo6ItG&scope=openid%20email%20profile%20offline_access%20model.request%20model.read%20organization.read&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fexplorer.api.openai.com%2Fapi%2Fauth%2Fcallback%2Fauth0&audience=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.openai.com%2Fv1&state=I_b9zgmBonH9_nyKm3pF45sBPZeYhEIVdYNduPXP1KU&code_challenge=DjrdWVogz4KP6iQtmtbByQzqeFIO0_rckquiiEwCgxc&code_challenge_method=S256"

    // decode url
    decodedUrl, err := url.QueryUnescape(originUrl)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("decode err")
    }
    // send request
    response, err := http.Get(decodedUrl)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("send failure：", err)
        return
    }
    defer response.Body.Close()
    // out put ans
    fmt.Println(response.Status)
}
```

the golang out put

```
2023-02-18T03:21:21+08:00 warning layer=rpc Listening for remote connections (connections are not authenticated nor encrypted)
=== RUN   TestParseUrl
400 Bad Request
--- PASS: TestParseUrl (0.60s)
PASS
```

curl script

```
curl 'https://auth0.openai.com/authorize?client_id=TdJIcbe16WoTHtN95nyywh5E4yOo6ItG&scope=openid%20email%20profile%20offline_access%20model.request%20model.read%20organization.read&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fexplorer.api.openai.com%2Fapi%2Fauth%2Fcallback%2Fauth0&audience=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.openai.com%2Fv1&state=8vWnTRiDQxTo16Gz8TOu64QHCXTBxCraLMGKhR-TIMA&code_challenge=kWV8VapTwVi2EcjJnX0uk-vQPUn3k7BlrBGHTgdCFRc&code_challenge_method=S256' \
--compressed
```

curl out put

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFSfS.png)

i want fix this problom , idont know why golang will show 400 , could any one help me

Comment: Don't post text as images. This is bad behavior and generally will be ignored here.

Comment: this is curl out put comment: `200
{'Date': 'Fri, 17 Feb 2023 19:34:33 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'CF-Ray': '79b0f60c2fcf0993-HKG', 'Cache-Control': 'no-store, max-age=0, no-transform', 'Cont ........` httpcode is 200

Comment: You could just update your question by replacing the image with whatever text output you have in the console.

Comment: This site is behind Cloudflare CDN so they likely have some protection enabled against scripts.

Comment: Don't decode the URL. http.Get expects a properly encoded URL, just like curl does.

Comment: Also: set all necessary headers. When in doubt: Start with what curl sends.

Answer (score 0):

`decodedUrl` seems to be the issue to me, I would

```
    // keep the code above this
    fmt.Println(originUrl)


    // decode url
    decodedUrl, err := url.QueryUnescape(originUrl)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("decode err")
    }
    
    //then curl the url that is printed here
    fmt.Println(decodedUrl) // I expect curling this will be a bad request as well
```